# NMinimize error

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I want to use NMinimize in the following way:

```
Uni[phi_, psi_,theta_] := {{E^(I*phi)*Cos[theta], E^(I*psi)*Sin[theta]}, {-E^(-I*psi)*Sin[theta], E^(-I*phi)*Cos[theta]}}
LocalUni[a1_, a2_, a3_, b1_, b2_, b3_, c1_, c2_, c3_] := KroneckerProduct[Uni[a1, b1, c1], KroneckerProduct[Uni[a2, b2, c2], Uni[a3, b3, c3]]]
StateDifference[a1_, a2_, a3_, b1_, b2_, b3_, c1_, c2_, c3_] := RhoKnown - LocalUni[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2,  c3].RhoFound.ConjugateTranspose[LocalUni[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]]
```

so I have the function `StateDifference`, and I want to minimize its absolute value, in terms of the a1,a2... parameters. Thus I apply:

```
NMinimize[{Abs[N[StateDifference[m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9]]]}, {m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9}]
```

where I just replaced a1,a2, with m1,m2 etc (this should not matter).

The problem is when I run this:

```
The objective function {{Abs[<<1>>],Abs[(-0.0526+0.0765 I)+<<1>>+<<11>>],Abs[(0.1122 -0.0484 I)+<<12>>],Abs[<<12>>+2.71828^(Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]) <<1>> ((-0.113-0.0444 I) Power[<<2>>] Cos[<<1>>] Cos[<<1>>] Cos[<<1>>]-(0.0196 -0.1235 I) Power[<<2>>] Cos[<<1>>] Cos[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>]+(0.0062 +0.1358 I) Power[<<2>>] Cos[<<1>>] Cos[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>]-(0.1134 -0.0651 I) <<3>> Sin[<<1>>]+(<<1>>) <<4>>-(0.1036 -0.0864 I) Power[<<2>>] Cos[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>]+(0.0596 +0.1086 I) Power[<<2>>] Cos[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>]+(0.1218 +0.014 I) Power[<<2>>] Sin[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>])],Abs[(<<7>> +<<1>>)+<<12>>],Abs[<<1>>],Abs[<<1>>],Abs[(0.0314 +0.0286 I)+2.71828^(Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]) Conjugate[Sin[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>]] (<<1>>)+<<11>>]},<<7>>} should be scalar-valued. >>
```

The matrices `RhoKnown` and `RhoFound` are just 2 numerical 8x8 matrices. (Hermitian and of trace 1).

Answer (score 2):

The problem resides in the fact that I was minimizing over a matrix not a number. This can be done, however, over the sum of the total matrix elements, by using the line:

```
FinalFunct[a1_, a2_, a3_, b1_, b2_, b3_, c1_, c2_, c3_] := Sum[StateDifference[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2,c3][[k]][[k]], {k, 1,   Length[StateDifference[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]]}]
```

and using NMinimize on this function. My apologies for not seeing this before posting the question.